# how to move function to class? python

Tags: python, class-attributes

I would like to to use service functions in a classmethod, where the service function is defined somewhere else. I want to be dynamic, so I can define different functions in different situations. I've tried this:

```
def print_a():
    print 'a'

class A:
    func = print_a
    @classmethod
    def apply(cls):
        cls.func()

A.apply()
```

Yet I receive this error:

`unbound method print_a() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 6):

you can use **call**

```
def print_a():
    print 'a'

class A:

    func = print_a.__call__

    @classmethod
    def apply(cls):
        cls.func()

A.apply()
```

**Output**

```
a
```